# SharePoint Framework: webpart does not show in workbench

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I see no errors when I execute gulp serve, the workbench based on the tenant is up, but there is no webpart I have created. The other, already existing, non-custom webparts appear but there is no custom webarpts.

One thing that might cause this is the fact that I am executing gulp serve under admin account on the box, while the workbench is brough up under my regular account. Please confirm this for me, if this is causing the issue, if not - please let me know what might be causing the above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to shift+left click in order to run the browser under the admin account. Authentication in the browser can be done with AD account and the webparts will appear in the workbench.

Regards